# Incorrect symbols: Devise returns syntax error when coloring text on buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, devise

I am configuring an upload form for a crowdfunding site.

The following code works. It gives me white text on the Edit Profile button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success large"><%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => 'navbar-link' "css-class"}%></button>
```

But when I try and add colors to the following line, Devise returns a syntax error:

```
<button class="btn btn-success large"><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => 'navbar-link' "css-class"}%></button>
```

The problem is incorrect syntax/symbols between the words `:delete` and `{:style`. I have followed the error messages and tried every combination of symbols `, : => (` and `{` but none are correct.

I'm making a syntax error, but am not sure what. Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete,:style=>"color:#FFFFFF;", :class => "navbar-link css-class" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error:
Replace

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => 'navbar-link' "css-class"}%>
```

with

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => 'navbar-link' "css-class"}%>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just FYI, that still returns an error. Preethi's answer was correct.